# How to create a input autosuggest or select option search using ionic react?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, autosuggest

I want to implement searchable select or input autosuggest in my ionic application using react. I searching too many way but did not find any solution. Here is an example what I want.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

if you don't have a lot of content, this approach might work?

```
<input type="text" id="programming_language" list="languages"/>
<datalist id="languages">
 <option value="JavaScript"></option>
 <option value="Python"></option>
 <option value="Java"></option>
 <option value="HTML">Stop being a troll</option>
</datalist>
```

see blog post here: https://dev.to/nialljoemaher/easy-autocomplete-suggestions-for-inputs-with-just-html5-datalist-tag-32j1